# fengyuanchen jquery cropper plugin with multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the fengyuanchen jquery cropper from [here](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/).  I have it working great with a single image.  Now I want to add a second image in.  So when the user uploads an image, it will load that same image into 2 different cropper boxes of different dimensions.  It is doing that, but the second preview is not getting shown.  Part of the comments in the preview image code section say: "// Revoke when load complete" so I'm wondering if that is part of the reason why it is not showing.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="inputImage" name="inputImage" type="file" accept="image/*"><div class="message"> </div>
</div>
<label class="col-md-1">Item #:</label>
<div class="col-md-1"><input type="text" id="itemNum" name="itemNum" /></div>
<div class="col-md-7" id="itemName"></div>
</div>
<div class="large-product-image">
<h2>Large Product Image (400x500)</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="img-container col-md-6" style=" display: block;width: 450px; height: 550px; left: 0 !important; top: 0 !important;">
            <img alt="mainImage" id="mainImageL" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/400x500-template.png")" style="width: 450px; height: 550px; left: 0 !important; top: 0 !important;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
            Cropped Large Image<br />
            <div id="croppedLarge"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="resetLargeImage">Reset Image</button> <button class="btn btn-primary" id="saveLargeImage">Save Image</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="small-product-image">
<h2>Small Product Image (300x174)</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="img-container col-md-6" style=" display: block;width: 350px; height: 224px; left: 0 !important; top: 0 !important;">
            <img alt="mainImage" id="mainImageS" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/300X174-template.png")" style="width: 350px; height: 220px; left: 0 !important; top: 0 !important;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
            Cropped Small Image<br />
            <div id="croppedSmall"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="resetImage">Reset Image</button> <button class="btn btn-primary" id="saveImage">Save Image</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#itemNum").blur(function () {
                var itemNum = $(this).val().trim();
                if (itemNum.length > 0) {
                    $("#itemName").html("looking up item number...");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("getItemName", "Home")',
                        data: {
                            itemNum: itemNum
                        },
                        success: function (name) {
                            $("#itemName").html(name);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            (function () {
                var canvas = 0;
                var $largeImage = $('#mainImageL'),
                  $smallImage = $('#mainImageS'),
                  $dataRotate = $('#dataRotate'),
                  options = {
                      modal: true,
                      guides: true,
                      autoCrop: true,
                      autoCropArea: 1, // Center 60%
                      dragCrop: false,
                      movable: true,
                      resizable: true,
                      zoomable: true,
                      touchDragZoom: false,
                      mouseWheelZoom: true,
                      preview: '#croppedLarge',
                      cropBoxResizable: false,
                      cropBoxMovable: false,
                      doubleClickToggle: false,
                      aspectRatio: 400 / 500,
                      crop: function (data) {
                          $dataRotate.val(Math.round(data.rotate));
                      }
                  },
                  optionsSmall = {
                      modal: true,
                      guides: true,
                      autoCrop: true,
                      autoCropArea: 1, // Center 60%
                      dragCrop: false,
                      movable: true,
                      resizable: true,
                      zoomable: true,
                      touchDragZoom: false,
                      mouseWheelZoom: true,
                      preview: '#croppedSmall',
                      cropBoxResizable: false,
                      cropBoxMovable: false,
                      doubleClickToggle: false,
                      aspectRatio: 300 / 174,
                      crop: function (data) {
                          $dataRotate.val(Math.round(data.rotate));
                      }
                  };

                $("#saveLargeImage").click(function () {
                    var itemNum = $(this).val().trim();
                    if (itemNum.length > 0) {
                        $largeImage.cropper('getCroppedCanvas', {
                            width: 400,
                            height: 500
                        }).toBlob(function (blob) {
                            var formData = new FormData();
                            formData.append('croppedImage', blob, $("#inputImage").val());

                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("uploadImage", "Home")',
                                method: "POST",
                                data: formData,
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                success: function () {
                                    console.log('Upload success');
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                                    console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
                                }
                            });
                        }, "image/jpeg");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#itemName").html("<span class='warn'>Please enter an item number!</span>");
                    }
                });

                var $previewL = $("#croppedLarge"),
                  widthL = $previewL.width();

                var $previewS = $("#croppedSmall"),
                  widthS = $previewS.width();

                var $largeInputImage = $('#inputImage'),
                URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
                blobURL;

                $("#resetLargeImage").click(function () {
                    $largeImage.cropper('reset');
                });

                if (URL) {
                    $largeInputImage.change(function () {
                        var files = this.files,
                            file;
                        this.width = 0;
                        this.height = 0;
                        if (files && files.length) {
                            file = files[0];

                            img = new Image();

                            img.onload = function () {
                                imageLoaded(this.width, this.height, file)
                            };
                            img.onerror = function () {
                                alert("not a valid file: " + file.type);
                            };
                            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $largeImage.parent().remove();
                    $smallImage.parent().remove();
                }

                function imageLoaded(width, height, file) {
                    if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type) && width >= 400 && height >= 500) {
                        blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        $largeImage.on().cropper(options);
                        $largeImage.one('built.cropper', function () {
                            URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL); // Revoke when load complete
                        }).cropper('reset', true).cropper('replace', blobURL);
                        //$imageLarge.on().cropper(options);
                        var $previewL = $("#croppedLarge"),
                        widthL = $previewL.width();
                        $smallImage.on().cropper(optionsSmall);
                        $smallImage.one('built.cropper', function () {
                            URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL); // Revoke when load complete
                        }).cropper('reset', true).cropper('replace', blobURL);
                        var $previewS = $("#croppedSmall"),
                        widthS = $previewS.width();
                        $(".message").html(' ');
                    } else {
                        $(".message").html('Please choose an image file with a width at least 400px and height at least 500px. ' + width + ' - ' + height);
                        $largeImage.cropper("destroy");
                        $largeInputImage.val('');
                    }
                }

                function resetImage($image) {

                }
            }());
        });
    </script>
```